# mysql - if statement inside a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Name    Value   AnotherColumn
-----------
Pump 1  8000    Something1
Pump 1  1000    Something2
Pump 1  3000    Something3
Pump 2  3043    Something4
Pump 2  4594    Something5
Pump 2  6165    Something6
```

In this table I want to group by on Name column and give output as name,value_exist.

value_exist will be 1 if 1000 is present in any of the value column for that name group. so the output will be:

```
Name    value_exist
-----------
Pump 1  1
Pump 2  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
select name, MAX(CASE WHEN value=1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as value_exist
from your_table
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

One more :

```
select name , max(if(value=1000,1,0)) as value_exist
from table 
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, sum(value = 1000) as value_exist
from your_table
group by name
```